# Using HTML DOM in google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can you use Html DOM in google chrome extension to...

1) write/Auto fill in a form?

2) Read values in label? Textboxes? And use them in your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes, and yes. See the [Content Scripts API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html).

Comment: "1) write/Auto fill in a form?" with assigned values passed by your program variables?

Comment: Yes, you pass in data from through from your extension to the content script that is loaded on the page.